# Get Ldap server version with java

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

I found this simple example with java how to connect to LDAP server:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

import java.util.Hashtable;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to create an initial context to an LDAP server
 * using SSL. For this example to work, JSSE must be installed and
 * configured, and the issuer of the LDAP server's certificate must 
 * be in the JSSE trust store.
 *
 * usage: java Ssl
 */
class Ssl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set up environment for creating initial context
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:636/o=JNDITutorial");

        // Specify SSL
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

        // Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=S. User, ou=NewHires, o=JNDITutorial");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mysecret");

        try {
            // Create initial context
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            System.out.println(ctx.lookup("ou=NewHires"));

            // ... do something useful with ctx

            // Close the context when we're done
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the LDAP server and version when I'm connected?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Determine%20LDAP%20Server%20Vendor where we provide some methods we have found to generally work. There is no single method that works on all LDAP server implementations.

Also LDAP Version is too vague. Do you want: The [LDAPSupported Version](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/SupportedLDAPVersion)?  or The [vendorVersion](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/VendorVersion) of LDAP?

Also, some rootDSE entries may not be available unless you are bound with an account with proper permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Get the attributes of the rootDSE. Depending on the server, this information may be in there.

Comment: Your provider URL contains the rootDSE, so in this case just lookup("") from your initial context. That returns a DirContext for the rootDSE. Get the attributes from that. You'll find all sorts of interesting stuff there.